# Cannot finish Kubuntu installation, hangs on "configuring hardware 66%" or "configuring boot loader"

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, kubuntu

I have a 2 in 1 Acer Switch 3 tablet from which I had removed windows and decided to put Linux instead.

I was mostly following [this](https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/538305/cant-access-uefi-after-installing-linux-dual-boot) link, if I do this the most straightforward way (disable secure boot) installation will hang on after "configuring boot loader" and not progress anywhere. If I do according to the guide (don't disable secure boot but add boot exception) it hangs on "configuring hardware 66%". I can still fiddle around in live version but nothing else, I tried different distro and they don't even boot, it seems 32bit UEFI has to do something with it but I don't know enough to understand.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

disable secure boot
enable - if possible in bios - legacy mode

use standar ubuntu, dont use kubuntu until standar ubuntu works - kubuntu is great but it can get buggy - so stick to either ubuntu mate Or plain ubuntu just until you get a working installation.

if you did set the computer to legacy, when you select the boot usb drive to boot, you will see the same drive name, twice, BUT one of them says uefi and the other one just the drive name- that one is the legacy mode.
So, if you are able to see the "just the drive name" select that and proceed to install. you wont face the "grub" stuck at 66% or later on.

be aware, NOT ALL computers are able to run linux, and specially MANY Acer models... microsoft pays or gives discounts to Acer so they make it so ONLY windows 10 works! not even windows 8... i bought a laptop 6 monhts ago and i cant install linux.. i can get it to install by manually selecting the grub drive, making partitions, etc. it get to install but it never ever boots linux! hope your 2 in 1 is not one of those..

good luck!